# who calls url_for(options=nil), and when?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

In ruby 1.9.3 and rails 3.2.6, I built a simplest project:

```
rails _3.2.6_ new subdomains
rails g scaffold Blog name:string subdomain:string
```

then, I add a blank function

```
def url_for(options = nil) {}
```

into the file app/helper/url_helper.rb

and append a line into `app/controller/application_controller.rb`

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  include UrlHelper
end
```

After running, when I click the button `Create Blog` of the page `http://localhost:3000/blogs/new`, I alway got the error:

```
No route matches [POST] "/blogs/new"
```

I don't know who calls this function `url_for` with parameter `:controller => 'blogs', :action => 'new'`, when?

I know I must miss some basic knowledge about rails, any advice will be appreciated!

Comment: I'm not sure if you're just playing around, but you don't have to build your own `url_for`. There is already a method with the same name provided by Rails for you to use.

Comment: @meagar Of course I don't know why I build my own `url_for`, because the snippet is from [here](https://github.com/ryanb/railscasts-episodes/blob/master/episode-221/blogs/app/helpers/url_helper.rb) , and you know that project was created 5 years ago, so if I want to understand [#221 Subdomains in Rails 3](http://railscasts.com/episodes/221-subdomains-in-rails-3), I must create it using new version such as `ruby 1.9.3 and rails 3.2.6`. After I copy the code I got the following error, so I built a simplest project for understanding `url_for`

Comment: Trying to follow a 5-year-old tutorial on Rails is the most futile thing you could do. Find a newer tutorial, a 5 year old one is going to be *wrong* in many important ways, or just *entirely wrong*.

Comment: @meagar you are right, I should not follow the ancient tutorial, but I want to  follow the [shapado](https://github.com/ricodigo/shapado), which is the best FOSS Q/A platform based rails I found, but it use earlier resolution for subdomain

Answer (score 0):

Rails `form_for` helper in your view call `url_for` helper to create URL base on your object passed to `form_for`. [Here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#relying-on-record-identification) is described this functionality more detail.

Comment: there is no explanation about `usr_for` in your link page, but thank you!

Comment: [Here](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/RoutingUrlFor/url_for) is explained the same exactly (see `Relying on named routes` section).